# Social Login Pro Error:

Tags: error

When logging in with Social Login Pro I get this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '-7200' in 'where clause'

SELECT `ip_address`, `user_agent` FROM (`exp_sessions`) WHERE `member_id` = '75' AND `-7200` IS NULL AND `site_id` = '1'

Filename: third_party/social_login_pro/mod.social_login_pro.php

Line Number: 1481
```

**My system:**

EE Version: 2.9.0
Social Login Pro version: 1.8.0

Comment: Even after reinstalling the Module / Extension i get the same error.

Comment: The developer seems to be actively supporting this on devotee.  http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/social-login-pro/viewforum/1783  This looks like a bug to me, as this version was only released last week he'd probably like to hear about it.